# React Apollo Client, loading only change to true on first time query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, request, apollo-client

I have a simple structure of files on a same directory (`./src/`)

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from "@apollo/client";
import Gql from "./Gql";

const App = () => {
  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri: "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Gql />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`Gql.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { gql, useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const Gql = () => {
  const [getQuery, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(gql`
    query {
      launchesPast(limit: 10) {
        mission_name
        launch_date_local
        launch_site {
          site_name_long
        }
      }
    }
  `);

  if (error) {
    return <div> Error . . .</div>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button
        style={{ padding: "20px" }}
        onClick={() => {
          getQuery();
        }}>
        Request Query
      </button>
      <div>Loading: {loading ? "true" : "false"}</div>
      <div>data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Gql;
```

[image]

The `loading` variable changed to true and to false on first request. But if I try to query it again and again without reloading the page. The `loading` variable stay the same while the browser have a valid XHR Request to the graphql server.

Comment: after the first request, from the second request onwards it seems the data on the page is not being updated either, is that correct? by that I mean `<div>data: {JSON.stringify(data)}</div>` still shows data from the first request ?

Comment: Yes it will stay the same. I didn't change the parameter of graphql request, so it will return the same data. As you can see on the right side of the .gif, I called the request 4 times.
You can try to see request yourself in this link: https://api.spacex.land/graphql/

Comment: hm, try changing the parameter & see if it updates. This might be by design, so the `useLazyQuery` hook has no reason to update data since params did not change.

Comment: glad I could help, should I add this as an answer so it is helpful to other folks who might run into this same issue?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design, the `useLazyQuery` hook will only run when the params change as this will then prevent useless re-renders.